# detecting input device removal using WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE

Tags: c++, winapi, usb

I have a very simple Windows application that listens for USB input device arrival and removal. for some reason the handle that is passed in the WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE message is always valid for arrival events but almost never valid for removal events. in InitInstance my application registers for raw input device messages like this:

```
// register for raw input device input messages
RAWINPUTDEVICE rid[2];
rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01;
rid[0].usUsage = 0x06;          // keyboard
rid[0].dwFlags =
   RIDEV_DEVNOTIFY |            // receive device arrival / removal messages
   RIDEV_INPUTSINK;             // receive messages even if not in foreground
rid[0].hwndTarget = hWnd;
rid[1].usUsagePage = 0x01;
rid[1].usUsage = 0x02;          // mouse
rid[1].dwFlags =
   RIDEV_DEVNOTIFY |
   RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
rid[1].hwndTarget = hWnd;

if (RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, 2, sizeof(rid[0])) == FALSE)
{
   DisplayLastError(TEXT("Failed to register for raw input devices"), hWnd);
   return FALSE;
}
return TRUE;
```

and in WndProc my application handles WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE messages like this:

```
    case WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE:
    {
        std::wstring action = wParam == GIDC_ARRIVAL ? L"arrival" : L"removal";
        TCHAR ridDeviceName[256];
        UINT dwSize = 256;
        UINT dwResult = GetRawInputDeviceInfo((void*)lParam, RIDI_DEVICENAME, &ridDeviceName, &dwSize);
        if (dwResult == 0 || dwResult == UINT(-1))
        {
            //action = action.insert(0, L"Failed to get raw input device info during device ");
            //DisplayLastError(&action[0], hWnd);
            // -- THIS IS WHERE DEVICE REMOVAL MESSAGES KEEP ENDING UP
            OutputDebugString((L"Received WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE with parameter: " + action + L" for USB device with handle: " + std::to_wstring(lParam) + L"\n").c_str());
        }
        else
        {
            const std::wstring devicePath(ridDeviceName);
            OutputDebugString((L"Received WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE with parameter: " + action + L" for USB device with path: " + devicePath + L"\n").c_str());
        }
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    break;
```

what happens on device removal: GetLastError reports error 6 = the handle is invalid, dwResult = UINT(-1) which as commented would mean that the buffer is insufficient but dwSize is still set at 256 and even if I retry with a buffer and dwSize of 4096 it still fails and dwSize then is still set to 4096, meanwhile I've also seen negative values for lParam and that doesn't look like a valid handle value indeed..

am I doing something wrong here? MSDN says lParam should have a handle to the device so why is it almost never valid on device removal? is there a different way to detect device removal that should be used instead?

PS: I am testing by adding and removing keyboards to my laptop, docking station, and USB hubs and I have Windows 7 x64. My application also listens to WM_INPUT messages, but that's for input only.

Comment: The documentation for [`GetRawInputDeviceInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms645597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that if it returns `-1`, then it means that the `pData` parameter is not big enough. In that case, your `dwSize` should now tell you the required size, so you can allocate space and try again. Note, I've not tried this API, I'm just reading the documentation.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the question with some findings I should have reported earlier..

Comment: A negative value for `lParam` should be fine, you're just casting it to a `HANDLE` anyway (or you _should_ be). It's only an issue if the value is `-1`, which can mean it's an invalid handle.

Answer (score 0):

I guess handle is already closed on `GIDC_REMOVAL` by design.

You can just call `GetRawInputDeviceInfo()` on `GIDC_ARRIVAL` and save this info in some persistent place - for example in `static std::map<HANDLE, std::wstring>`.

If you need this info on `GIDC_REMOVAL` event you can just call `map[(HANDLE)lParam]` to request it.

Also do not forget to call `map.remove((HANDLE)lParam)` on the end of `GIDC_REMOVAL` event processing so you will always have list of currenly connected device's handles.